# Pandas on Apple Silicon M1 chip within the Ubuntu container

Tags: python, pandas, docker, apple-m1

I have a trouble understanding the issue here:
We have

- Docker image `ubuntu:20.04`
- MacBook Pro on M1 chip
- Old pandas version wheel (legacy system)

Within our Docker image, we use Poetry to manage dependencies:

```
[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = ">=3.8,<3.9"

pandas = [
    { platform = "linux", url = "***/pandas-0.24.0-cp38-cp38-linux_x86_64.whl"},
    { platform = "darwin", markers="platform_machine=='x86_64'", url = "***/pandas-0.24.0-cp38-cp38-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl" },
    { platform = "darwin", markers="platform_machine=='arm64'", url = "***/pandas-0.24.0-cp38-cp38-macosx_12_0_arm64.whl" }
]
```

But when we try to build this image on the M1 machine, we face the error `ERROR: pandas-0.24.0-cp38-cp38-linux_x86_64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.`, but it clearly tries to install ubuntu `whl`, since it is running within Docker image.

When we build the same image on a Linux machine (in CI/CD), everything works fine.

How can we build an image on M1 chip and on Ubuntu?

Comment: I ran to a similar issue, trying to build GPU related image. Somehow I couldn't figure out a way to build the image in M1 to support GPU architecture in Linux. I did come across ```docker buildx``` command. But not a definite resolve. I'll do some research on this and also monitor answers for insights. Thanks for the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

M1 is an arm64-based chip, but you try to install pandas for x86_64.
I'm not a pythonist, but looks like you need to add a dependency for linux arm64:

```
pandas = [
    { platform = "linux", markers="platform_machine=='arm64'" … # <- here
    { platform = "linux", markers="platform_machine=='x86_64'", url = "***/pandas-0.24.0-cp38-cp38-linux_x86_64.whl"},
    { platform = "darwin", markers="platform_machine=='x86_64'", url = "***/pandas-0.24.0-cp38-cp38-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl" },
    { platform = "darwin", markers="platform_machine=='arm64'", url = "***/pandas-0.24.0-cp38-cp38-macosx_12_0_arm64.whl" }
]
```